# MonoTouch: UIApplicationDelegate - is OnActivated needed?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

An older version of MonoTouch added the following code from its template. Is this still needed?

```
    // This method is required in iPhoneOS 3.0
    public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app will run on iOS 3, yes it is still needed. Otherwise, you only need it to capture  when your app transitions to the active state (eg. when the multitasking bar is displayed and you get back to your app when you tap on it).